# How to run only one instance of code in a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I listen for a `onload` event on a main window, then for a `DOMContentLoaded` event on each browser/tab (I need run the code inside a browser at the most) and flag with `controlExecuted` that the code was run on a browser.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    try{
        var controlExecuted = 0;
        var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent"); // browser
        if (appcontent && controlExecuted == 0)
            appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function docLoader(e){
                appcontent.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docLoader, false);
                alert('run code')
                controlExecuted = 1;
            }, true);
    }catch(e){
        // log!
    }
}, false);
```

This not works. The code run several times depending of the number of browsers/tabs.

So how to run only one instance of code in a firefox addon?

Comment: What happens if you move the `controlExecuted` variable outside the `load` listener?  Isn't that just creating a new variable each time `load` fires on `window`?

Comment: `controlExecuted` is created each time a windows is created. That's fine. Before or after `load` is not important. I tried anyway and no luck. THX,.

Comment: But won't it also be created for any `load` event which bubbles up from each window?

Comment: @robertc Not really sure about what you say. If you refer to the scope involved: I use `controlExecuted` as a flag, and for the matter, works the same before or after `load` event, and is created just one time by any created window. But it's truth that I need control other windows too. I have already solve this issue and I'll add a suitable answer to this question ASAP. THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the complete solution to run only one instance of code in a firefox addon using [JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using).

```
// modules/main.jsm
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["instancesControl"];

var instancesControl = {
    executed : 0,
    windowExecuting : 0,

    get : function(){
        return ++instancesControl.executed;
    },
    reset : function(){
        instancesControl.executed = 0;
    },
    getWindowExecuting : function(){
        return instancesControl.windowExecuting;
    },
    setWindowExecuting : function(id){
        instancesControl.windowExecuting = id;
    }   
};
```

The main calling code:

```
 // load instancesControl module
Components.utils.import("resource://my-own-alias/main.jsm");

// identify window that will execute the one-instance code
var util = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);
var windowID = util.outerWindowID;

// listen load window event 
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
    if (appcontent){
        // listen load content (on every tab)
        appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function docLoader(e){
            appcontent.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docLoader, false);
            if (instancesControl.get() == 1){
                instancesControl.setWindowExecuting(windowID);

                // this code will run only once no matter
                // how many tabs or windows user opens.

            }
        }, true);
    }
}, false);

// re-init code if executing windows is closed
window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
    if (instancesControl.getWindowExecuting() == windowID){
        instancesControl.reset();
    }
}, false);
```

Sure that you can improve it. Comment using @nomikos if you do.
THX.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, your code runs each time a new browser window is opened. What you might not have realized is that a script in one window is **completely independent** of the same script in another window. That is, a new set of objects is instantiated each time, which means that `controlExecuted` in one window is not the same object as `controlExecuted` in another window.

There are two broad ways to share code in an extension:

- Create an [XPCOM component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript). This is the classic, more difficult (but very powerful) method of sharing code in a browser extension.
- Create a [JavaScript code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using) (JSM). In short:

  > JavaScript code modules are a concept introduced in Gecko 1.9 and can
  >   be used for sharing code between different privileged scopes. Modules
  >   can also be used to create global JavaScript singletons that
  >   previously required using JavaScript XPCOM objects.

You might also consider setting this flag as a **user preference**, which each instance of your script can read. This might be the easiest approach for such a simple use case.

Comment: +1 Code run on every tab (of every window) as well. `controlExecuted` is the same for each tab so can be used as flag. But you right. Share code between windows is not trivial. I used "javaScript code module". I added an answer with the code. THX.